# Delete not working when using SET LOCK MODE TO WAIT with Informix

Tags: c#, server, client, informix

Recently we had `Informix` upgraded `11.7` to `12.10`. After this deleting functionality not working as expected. Here is example query we are using:

```
 SET LOCK MODE TO WAIT TO 5;
 BEGIN WORK;
 DELETE FROM DOCUMENT WHERE DOCUMENT_ID = 1000;
 COMMIT WORK;
```

Above query not deleting any records and in some cases tables getting locked. 
But same worked without any issues before upgrade.

And another interesting observation is, below query working without any issues

```
-- (SET LOCK MODE not used here):
BEGIN WORK;
DELETE FROM DOCUMENT WHERE DOCUMENT_ID = 1000;
COMMIT WORK;
```

We are using IBM Data Server Client 10.5.3 to connect to then Informix server using C#.

Comment: This sounds like a problem that should be taken to IBM/Informix Technical Support.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. Working with them as well, will post answer if we receive any updates from them.